# Ruby rails heroku I have added pg to gemfile yet it says it did not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to git push heroku master my app into production for heroku, and despite the fact that my gemfile looks like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.18.3'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and I do :

```
bundle install --without production
```

and

```
git commit -a -m
```

and finally

```
git push heroku master
```

it will reject the transfer saying that pg is not installed in gemfile

```
 Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

So, when I do `heroku open`

I get this

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I dont know if the two errors are related. Heroku did upload my id_rsa.pub key and I did log in via command line through emails and pwd.

Answer (score -1):

So this is where I think the error was, in case someone goes through the same.

1) when I tried to create a ssh key through

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

despite the fact that I do have ssh installed by default on my linux it that command did not work at first, so I ended up generating in through a ssh keygene command. I copied it and pasted it (the public one) in my bitbucket ssh keys, but the private one which had been generated did not match with the original one. and the error was due to this mismatch of keys between the private local and public.

I think I also messed up as I was using two different computers and if you do that you have to go on to another schema of different keys for the same account etc.
I restarted from scratch, I deleted my git directory, i deleted my repository at bitbucket and the app at heroku and tried that command again.

For some reason this time the command worked (no, it was not misspelled the first time), so now the synchronization of keys was correct. This time I copied it and pasted it straightway in the ssh keys of bitbucket.

and I went trough the same stuff again like this:

This follows the instructions from the great book by Michael Hartl (The Ruby on Rails Tutorial)

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<username>/hello_app.git
$ git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
```

$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:myname/hello_app.git

now for the gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.18.3'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

$ bundle install --without production
```

curiously now it did not complain about the pg but about mysql2, so this really does not matter much appearingly

```
$ git commit -a -m "Update Gemfile.lock for Heroku"
$ heroku version
$ heroku login
$ heroku keys:add
```

(this time the keys were added or fetched correctly)

```
$ heroku create
Creating damp-fortress-5769... done, stack is cedar
http://damp-fortress-5769.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:damp-fortress-5769.git
Git remote heroku added

$ git push heroku master

heroku open
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer.